# YAML Parser error on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, pyyaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm getting the following error on my azure devop pipeline, it seems to relate towards parameters loop but despite writing the script multiple different ways I can't seem to get rid of it. YAML validators and my YAML linter don't detect an issue.

`/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 1, Col: 12): Unexpected value ''`

Below is my code, it uses a template as well, which I will include beneath it.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
parameters:
steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: 'Setting python version to 3.7'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.7'
      architecture: 'x64'

  - script: |
      pushd '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}'
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: 'Install prerequisites'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive files'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'
      artifactName: 'drop'

  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
    
    inputs:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: $(serviceConnectionName)
      subscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
      resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
      location: $(resourceGroupLocation)
      csmFile: 'deployment_template.json'
      overrideParameters: '-appName ${{ project }} -storageAcctName $(storageAcctName)  -hostingPlanName $(hostingPlanName)'

  - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
      appType: functionAppLinux
      appName: ${{ project }}
      package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'
```

Template - deploy-functions.yml

```
trigger:
  - main

variables:
  - group: 'AzFunctionsAppVariableGroup'
    
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  
steps:
- template: azure-pipelines.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
    - ProjectName1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I throw your azure-pipelines.yml into the pipeline editor in Azure DevOps, it marks the line ending of ***parameters:*** with the warning

> "Incorrect type. Expected "array"."

I didn't work with templates on pipelines so far, but from the [MS doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters), it seems that you need to specify the parameters that you are passing like so:

```
#azure-pipelines.yml

parameters:
- name: projects
  type: object #object, since you are passing a list of strings
steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
#...
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much for the help

Comment: thanks not easy to figure it out from MS doc examples

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested that you could enable the feature of YAML template editor with picture below and process the test.

[image: preview features]
[image: Yaml templates editor]